# How to call the fzf Ag command with multiple arguments?

Tags: vimscript, the-silver-searcher, argument-list, plugin-fzf

The plugin fzf.vim defines the following vim command [here](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/blob/master/plugin/fzf.vim#L51):

```
command!      -bang -nargs=* Ag   call fzf#vim#ag(<q-args>, <bang>0)'
```

the `fzt#vim#ag` function seems to allow passing all the ag options to the ag shell command. There is also a [comment regarding this](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/blob/master/autoload/fzf/vim.vim#L654)

```
" query, [[ag options], options]
function! fzf#vim#ag(query, ...)
```

However, no matter how I call it everything is passed as the first parameter `query`. I've added bunch of logs to the script

For example, calling

```
:Ag SearchString -c app
```

and adding following logs to the above function

```
" query, [[ag options], options]
function! fzf#vim#ag(query, ...)
  if type(a:query) != s:TYPE.string
    return s:warn('Invalid query argument')
  endif
  let query = empty(a:query) ? '^(?=.)' : a:query
  let args = copy(a:000)
  let ag_opts = len(args) > 1 && type(args[0]) == s:TYPE.string ? remove(args, 0) : ''
  let command = ag_opts . ' ' . fzf#shellescape(query)
  echo query
  echo ag_opts
  echo command
  return call('fzf#vim#ag_raw', insert(args, command, 0))
endfunction
```

would print

```
SearchString -c app
 'SearchString -c app'
```

meaning `ag_opts` was empty

So how to pass the other args as a query to this command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR: You can't pass `ag` options into *that* command. (But jump to the bottom for a different one.)**

Note the distinction between the `:Ag` command and the `fzf#vim#ag` function.

The `:Ag` command calls the `fzf#vim#ag` function passing it exactly two arguments:

1. `<q-args>`: This is *all* the arguments that were passed to the *command*, passed as a *single* argument. (See `:h <q-args>`.)
2. `<bang>0`: `<bang>` evaluates to `!` if you typed an exclamation point after your command `:Ag!` and nothing if you didn't. (See `:help <bang>`.) So if you *didn't* type an exclamation point then `0` is passed as the second argument. And if you *did*, then `!0` is passed, i.e. the negation of `0`, i.e. `1`. (Try typing `:echo !0` into Vim.)

The function takes `fzf#vim#ag` is defined with the signature:

```
function! fzf#vim#ag(query, ...)
```

Which means that inside the function:

- The variable `a:query` will contain the first argument to the function i.e. *all* the arguments that were passed to the command.
- The variable `a:000` will either be the list `[0]` or the list `[1]`, depending on whether or not you used an exclamation point after the `:Ag` command.

Inside the function `ag_opts` is set with the lines:

```
let args = copy(a:000)
let ag_opts = len(args) > 1 && type(args[0]) == s:TYPE.string ? remove(args, 0) : ''
```

The first line just makes a copy of the list: `a:000`.

The second line then checks if the length of the list is greater than one. When called from the `:Ag` command it never is, so `ag_opts` is therefore *always* set to the empty string: ''.

Therefore, if you want to pass options to the `ag` executable, you cannot do it with the command you described in your question: I don't know whether the `fzf` plugin currently offers different commands, or whether you will need to write your own, like [this one by the author of fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/92#issuecomment-191248596):

```
function! s:ag_with_opts(arg, bang)
  let tokens  = split(a:arg)
  let ag_opts = join(filter(copy(tokens), 'v:val =~ "^-"'))
  let query   = join(filter(copy(tokens), 'v:val !~ "^-"'))
  call fzf#vim#ag(query, ag_opts, a:bang ? {} : {'down': '40%'})
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * command! -nargs=* -bang Ag call s:ag_with_opts(<q-args>, <bang>0)
```

Comment: that should be pull request to fzf vim. awesome. just figured out what <q-args> really does and wanted to close this

Comment: @dre-hh There's not really any reason I can see to close this question. Feel free to accept my answer if you feel that it has answered your question, though!

Comment: fzf recently changed how it defined the :Ag command, it now does this:
`command!      -bang -nargs=* Ag                        call fzf#vim#ag(<q-args>, s:p(<bang>0), <bang>0)`

It calls the function s:p() to optionally add arguments to show the preview window. anyone using a wrapper around fzf#vim#ag will not get preview windows unless they adapt their wrapper

Comment: @PatrickZiegler Thanks for the tipoff. I'll try to incorporate the information in my answer when I get a chance (or you're welcome to make an edit).

Comment: @Rich Unfortunately I haven't found a satisfying solution to this. Currently I just copied fzf's s:p() function verbatim